# Is smart query custom variable name possible?

Tags: vue.js, vue-apollo

I'm using `Vue` alongside with `Apollo` in order to query a `GraphQL` endpoint in my project. Everything's fine but I want to start programming generic components to ease and fasten the development.

The thing is, in most views, I use the [Smart Query](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/api/smart-query.html#smart-query) system.
For instance, I use :

```
  apollo: {
    group: {
      query: GROUP_QUERY,
      variables () { return { id: this.groupId } },
      skip () { return this.groupId === undefined },
      result ({ data }) {
        this.form.name = data.group.name
      }
    }
  }
```

With the `GROUP_QUERY` that is :

```
const GROUP_QUERY = gql`
  query groupQuery ($id: ID) {
    group (id: $id) {
      id
      name
      usersCount
      userIds {
        id
        username
      }
    }
  }
`
```

So my `group` variable in my apollo smart query has the same name as the query itself `group (id: $id)`. It is this mechanism that is quite annoying for what I try to achieve. Is there a way to avoid that default mechanism ?

I'd like for instance to be able to give a generic name such as `record`, and it would be `records` for queries that potentially return multiple records.

With that, I would be able to make generic components or mixins that operate either on `record` or `records`.

Or have I to rename all my queries to `record` and `records` which would be annoying later on in case of troubleshooting with error messages ?

Or maybe there's another way to achieve that and I didn't think about it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing so :

```js
const GROUP_QUERY = gql`
  query groupQuery ($id: ID) {
    record: group (id: $id) {
      id
      name
      usersCount
      userIds {
        id
        username
      }
    }
  }
`
```

If the `GROUP_QUERY` is used at several places, the result will be accessible under the `record` name, because it is defined as an alias over `group`.
See documentation for [Aliases](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases).

Answer (score 0):

You can, in fact, rename the variable of Apollo smart queries using the `update` option, [as seen here in the Vue Apollo documentation](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/api/smart-query.html#options). Your example would look like:

```
  apollo: {
    record: {
      query: GROUP_QUERY,
      variables () { return { id: this.groupId } },

      update: (data) => data.group,

      skip () { return this.groupId === undefined },
      result ({ data }) {
        this.form.name = data.group.name
      }
    }
  }
```

You should notice that the Apollo object will create a `record` variable in your component, and the `update` statement shows where to get the `group` for the record.

Comment: Ye I finally figured out how to do it and I forgot to post it. In fact, an other name (alias) can be set on the query. And underneath the `GROUP_QUERY` has to specify this alias in order to use it. So the third line of my query would be : `record: group (id: $id)`